# sys.path behavior in vscode insiders is not equivalent to jupyter lab when using a virtual env

Tags: visual-studio-code, virtualenv, setuptools, jupyter-lab, sys.path

When switching to vscode-insiders notebooks  instead of jupyter lab, I noticed that importing my local `src` package installed using setuptools was not possible anymore, it throws a `ModuleNotFoundError`.

After comparing the two IDEs, it seems like vscode does not change `sys.path` as jupyter lab does.

My project architecture:

```
foo
└── bar
    └── myproject
        ├── notebooks
        │   └── nb.ipynb
        ├── setup.py
        ├── env
        └── src
```

My installation steps:

```
cd /foo/bar/myproject
source env/bin/activate
(env) python3 -m pip install -e .
(env) python3 -m ipykernel install --user --name=my_project_env # add the jupyter kernel based on the environment
```

Then opening nb.ipynb in both jupyterlab and vscode and checking sys.path gives the following:

jupyter lab:

```
print(sys.path)
-->
...
foo/bar/myproject # allows to import src
...
```

vscode:

```
print(sys.path)
-->
...
foo/bar/myproject/notebooks # does not allow to import src
...
```

I would have expected vscode to add the `foo/bar/myproject` directory to sys.path as it is the one where src is located, am I getting something wrong?

(In the meantime I found the following workaround, adding the following to my `settings.json` in vscode:

```
"jupyter.runStartupCommands":  [
        "import sys",
        "sys.path.insert(2,'${workspaceFolder}')"
    ]
```

)